# Change connectionstring in EF when swtiching database

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

were going to move our sites to another host and need to update our connectionstrings to point to the new database. Were using Entity Framework.

It is sufficient if I change the connectionstring in my web.config or do I need to change it in the edmx-file aswell?

Thx!

/Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating the connection string in web.config will be fine. I know as I've done it before.

You could test to be sure by copying your database and updating the connection string to use the copy.